# Lightweight OBJ mesh file loader for C/C++?

Tags: c++, input, geometry, mesh

I'm looking for a simple lightweight Wavefront OBJ mesh file reader for C or C++. (ie. given a mesh in OBJ format, read it in from a file, and make it accessible, preferably as a list of vertices and triangles.)  Recommendations?

It doesn't need to support material properties or any other fancy data that might be present - just the geometry is fine.

Comment: Please take a look at [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib#readme), specifically you need the function `MR::MeshLoad::fromObj`

Answer (score 3):

[Open Asset Import Library](http://www.assimp.org) looks very promising. [Plenty of formats](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) is supported.

Comment: @Athira Updated the links, they apparently migrated to GitHub