# How to load and render .obj model in Android Native language

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk, qcar-sdk

I would like to use Qualcomm's Augmented Reality SDK (Vuforia) with the min3D library and load obj model. How can I merge QCAR (Vuforia) with min3D? How to apply the projection and modelview matrixs of QCAR (Vuforia) to min3D? So that the scene is rendered correct in min3d.glsurfaceview? Has anyone developed an example?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of OBJ file loaders for C++. Check the following answer for more information.

[Lightweight OBJ mesh file loader for C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861458/lightweight-obj-mesh-file-loader-for-c-c)

Rendering a mesh in Android NDK is not simple as you think, you need to learn OpenGLES for that. Instead you can use many rendering engines that are already ported to Android NDK. I use Irrlicht for rendering our game. The Android port is very stable for basic rendering needs. There is already many 3d mesh format loaders built in with Irrlicht